# Add global variable in Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

How to add a global variable in Vue.js 3?

In Vue.js 2 we use this in the `main.js` file:

```
Vue.prototype.$myGlobalVariable = globalVariable
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897670/2815635

Comment: You can use Vuex to handle all global data

Comment: Yes of course, i can use the store or use a global mixin but I'm asking to use a prototype

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The most direct replacement is `app.config.globalProperties`. See:

https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties

So:

```js
Vue.prototype.$myGlobalVariable = globalVariable
```

becomes:

```js
const app = createApp(RootComponent)
app.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable = globalVariable
```

This is scoped to a particular application rather than being global as it was with `Vue.prototype`. This is by design, all 'global' configuration options are now scoped to an application.

The relevant RFC is here:

https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0009-global-api-change.md

Properties added to `globalProperties` will be available via the component instance for all components within the application. So if you're using the Options API you'll be able to access them using `this.$myGlobalVariable`, just like you could with `Vue.prototype`. They'll also be available in the template without the `this.`, e.g. `{{ $myGlobalVariable }}`.

If you're using the Composition API then you'll still be able to use these properties within the template, but you won't have access to the component instance within `setup`, so these properties won't be accessible there.

While hacks involving `getCurrentInstance()` can be used to access `globalProperties` within `setup`, those hacks involve using undocumented APIs and are not the recommended approach.

Instead, application-level `provide`/`inject` (also discussed in that RFC) can be used as an alternative to `Vue.prototype`:

```js
const app = createApp(RootComponent)
app.provide('myGlobalVariable', globalVariable)
```

In the descendant component this can then be accessed using `inject`. e.g. With `<script setup>`:

```html
<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'
const myGlobalVariable = inject('myGlobalVariable')
</script>
```

Or with an explicit `setup` function:

```js
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const myGlobalVariable = inject('myGlobalVariable')

    // Expose it to the template, if required
    return {
      myGlobalVariable
    }
  }
}
```

Or with the Options API:

```js
export default {
  inject: ['myGlobalVariable']
}
```

Docs: https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-provide

The idea here is that the component can explicitly declare the property rather than inheriting it by magic. That avoids problems like name collisions, so there's no need to use a `$` prefix. It can also help to make it clearer where exactly a property is coming from.

It is common for the `inject` function to be wrapped in a composable. For example, the `useRoute` composable exposed by Vue Router is just a wrapper around `inject`.

In addition to `globalProperties` and `provide`/`inject`, there are various other techniques that might be used to solve the same problems as `Vue.prototype`. For example, ES modules, stores, or even global mixins. These aren't necessarily direct answers to the specific question posted here, but I've gone into more detail describing the various approaches at:

https://skirtles-code.github.io/vue-examples/patterns/global-properties.html

Which approach you prefer will depend on your circumstances.

Comment: does this work with classes? doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: And how are the global variables accessed from the child components (In both cases)? Is it directly by calling `this.myGlobalVariable`?

Comment: Is there a way to declare global variables from outside the main app creation file? In Vue 2 I used to import Vue and then declare new global variables. I am struggling now since I need the `app` created by `createApp`.

Comment: M3HD1 - You can create a function that takes the application (`app` in the code above) as a parameter and does the `provide` (i.e. doProv = function(app) { app.provide(...); } and then just import it and call it in main.js or wherever you do your app creation/setup.

Comment: Your argumentation is solid, but you are notably not emphasizing the huge downside of the new approach. You need an extra line, i.e. `inject`, in every component where you want to access a global variable in CAPI!

Comment: that is a wonderful answer, thank you!

Comment: The problem I'm facing with `inject/provide` is that functions that rely on `this` execute in a different (caller's) scope. I want the provided functions to execute within the scope that they are defined in

Answer (score 43):

## How to add a global variable using Vue 3 and vue-cli (or Vite)

**Note:** You can drop the dollar sign from your `$globalVariable` and just use `globalVariable`, just like [in the documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties).

Initially your main.js file looks something like this (adding router for common use case):

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { App } from './App.vue'
import { router } from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

To use add the global variable **using Vue 3 and the vue-cli** or **Vite**:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { App } from './App.vue'
import { router } from './router'

// 1. Assign app to a variable
let app = createApp(App)

// 2. Assign the global variable before mounting
app.config.globalProperties.globalVar = 'globalVar'

// 3. Use router and mount app
app.use(router).mount('#app')
```

Then to access the variables in components like this:

```html
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            myVar: this.globalVar
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

like in the template like this:

```html
<template>
  <h1>{{ globalVar }}</h1>
</template>
```

And that's it. Happy coding!

### About Global Variables and Composition API

According to the *very* bottom of [samayo's answer on this post](https://coderedirect.com/questions/266855/how-to-use-vue-prototype-or-global-variable-in-vue-3), global variables are only available on the Options API.

Quoting the bottom of his answer:

> Note: This is only for the Options API. Evan You (Vue creator) says: "config.globalProperties are meant as an escape hatch for replicating the behavior of Vue.prototype. In setup functions, simply import what you need or explicitly use provide/inject to expose properties to app.

Comment: hey that's amazing!! thank you very much!! =)

Comment: Prefixing variables with some kind of "special character" makes it easier to signify in code that this variable is indeed special and probably comes from somewhere else. This makes coders more aware and development less error-prone.

Comment: @Coreus is there specific documentation that talks about this?

Comment: No, but it's a common practice for things that pollute the global scope. Think i.e jQuery for instance and their $. The approach was also commonly used in Vue 2 docs. As always, you're free to use whatever you want, in the same way you're free to drive off the side of the road instead of following it. You should probably look up the Rosetta Stone. Experience tells us that making them stand out (in some way) makes their significance easier to see.

Comment: Why provide an example with the options API in Vue 3? One of the biggest reasons to move to Vue 3 is the composition API with the script setup sugar.

Comment: @db2 Just updated. Apparently this isn't a feature for the composition api.

Comment: What if I want to call the `fetch` request first and then set the globalProperties? It always returns undefined because the app is mounting before setting `globalProperties`. I tried the mounting process after api call but still looking for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 33):

I recommend to use [`provide/inject`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html) approach as follows :

in main.js :

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'

const app=createApp({
  provide:{
    globalVariable:123
  }

}).$mount('#app')
```

in some child or grand-child component do :

```
export default{
 name:'some-compo',
 inject:['globalVariable'],
 //then access this.globalVariable as property in you component
...
}
```

for composition api and script setup :

```
 import { inject } from 'vue'
 
 const globalVar=inject('globalVariable')
```

Comment: createApp in my example is being passed a component, which has <script setup>. So how to pass provide in this case?

Comment: how can i achieve something similar to this inside a class ( not a component )
i mean how  can i use inject inside a class ?

Comment: Is it possible to inject multiple variables in one line?

Comment: @W.M. yes you could with options api, but in composition one you should assign each injected item in a specific variable

Comment: I have done it like this, `const global = {"$axios": axios,'$moment': moment,'$third': third,}; app.provide('$global ', global );` in `main.js`, and then inject the whole object when needed.

Comment: You're currently only linking to the options API provide/inject page, you should also link to the composition API provide/inject page: https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 17):

If possible you should use imports or provide/inject. Another way to define global variables/functions and use them would be using globalProperties (although this seems to be considered more of an anti-pattern). But if a library you use uses globalProperties then you can use it like this. This also works with global functions.

```
const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.config.globalProperties.$http = () => {} // global function
app.config.globalProperties.$globalVariable = 'Jimmy' // global variable
```

**1. Using options API**

```
mounted() {
  console.log(this.$globalVariable)
}
```

**2. Using setup method**

```
<script setup>
    import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

    const app = getCurrentInstance()
    const progressBar = app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$globalVariable

    console.log(this.$globalVariable)
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

For those of you who are confused about how to access `globalProperties` in the `setup()` method, you can use `getCurrentInstance()` as in the following documentation.

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance

Comment: From the documentation: "getCurrentInstance is only exposed for advanced use cases, typically in libraries. Usage of getCurrentInstance is strongly discouraged in application code. Do NOT use it as an escape hatch to get the equivalent of this in Composition API."

Answer (score 6):

Vue 3:

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from "vue";

const { proxy } = getCurrentInstance();
```

"proxy" will be contain the value from globalProperties. For example:

```
app.config.globalProperties.$toast = {...}
```

and then:

```
proxy.$toast.success()
```

Comment: My got I was looking for this everywhere. You my hero

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to create a global var and get the data from a script.
Used provide and inject:

In `main.js`:

```
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    const app = createApp(App);
    app.provide('message',document.querySelector('script[name="nameSCRIPT"]').innerHTML.split('=').slice(1).join('=').slice(1,-1));
    app.mount('#app')
```

In `index.html`:

```
 <script name="nameSCRIPT">nameSCRIPT="HELLO"</script>
```

In child component:

```
    inject:['message'],
    mounted(){
    console.log(this.message)
  },
```

Comment: It is very likely that your solution will sometimes break with an error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')`. Generally, DOM is about DISPLAY, but not about data storage. It's easier then to write a variable to `self` and read from there, although this is bad for a number of reasons

Answer (score -5):

window.myGlobal = "hey this is easy";

Comment: window is not guaranteed to be available.   especially in the tool chain for Vue.  It's only guaranteed in the browser.

Comment: global.myGlobal = "hey, im running in node"

Comment: const globalObject =  typeof window == 'undefined' ? global : window;
globalObject.someval = "works if I am unsure what context my code is run in. "

Comment: being that everything runs through a bundler like webpack, how do you know some other dependency doesn't include the code `window.myGlobal = 'something'?`  If the final bundle requires the existence of the global `window` variable to make use of the `window` global in a browser, the bundler can't alter the name of the variable `window` without also breaking the program.  I would just ditch this strategy from your repertoire.   I've ended up doing very difficult debugs before because of this.

Comment: That is a risk of using any global variable in any programming language.  If its a likely issue, it can be mitigated by appropriate naming.