# Vue 3: global import for ref, reactive and computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How do I import globally with `Vue 3` in the `main.js` the `ref`, `reactive` and `computed`?

I'm trying to avoid doing this in each component:

```js
import { ref, reactive, computed } from 'vue'
```

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100658/add-global-variable-in-vue-js-3

Comment: the other question was also mine lol. This is not the same thing

Comment: Why do you want to avoid such import statements? It tells you exactly what's needed in the component. Good for human eyes AND for programmatic eyes like tree-shaking.

Comment: yes you're right, I was young

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this is a good idea (it likely defeats tree shaking), but it's possible to make them global by adding them to `window`:

```js
// main.js
import { ref, reactive, computed } from 'vue'

window.ref = ref
window.reactive = reactive
window.computed = computed
```

If using ESLint, make sure to configure these globals:

```js
// eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    ref: true,
    reactive: true,
    computed: true,
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a really bad idea and (as @tony19 himself says) it shouldn't be encouraged.  It makes the functions global to the browser, but in Vue3, "global" doesn't mean "global-to-the-browser"; it means global to the Vue Application.  `ref`, `computed`, etc. should be appended to the Application object, not the window object, and it would still be accessible at the top-level in your Vue Components.  To any junior Devs coming across this thread, don't start doing this!  Other answers and comments on this thread point to more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i vue-global-api
// main.js
import 'vue-global-api'
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-global-api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).