# Making global plugin that I can use anywhere in app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have this class for sockets. Is there any way that I could make this globally accessible? I'd like to access the functions anywhere in my app for example like `$socket.methodName()`

What I've tried

```js
class InitSocket {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options;
  }

  connect() {
    console.log(this.options);
  }
}

export default {
  install: (Vue, options) => {
    Vue.prototype.$socket = new InitSocket(options);
  },
};
```

in main.js

```js
const { createApp } = require('vue');
import App from "./App.vue";
import Sockets from './plugins/Socket'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(Sockets , "test");
app.mount("#app");
```

But I am getting this message
`Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '$socket')` - What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add global variable in Vue.js 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100658/add-global-variable-in-vue-js-3)

Comment: Also it's a bad practice in Vue 3. There's not much use of $socket in templates, and in composition API there's no `this`. Just import it where you use it.

Comment: @EstusFlask but what if I have to use it in 20 components, I do not want to import it everywhere.

Comment: That's how modern JS works. IDEs handle imports for you. You'll have to do this any way with composition API. In order to not import it and use like `$socket.methodName()` (no `this`) you'd have to assign it to `window`, which is an absolute no-no.

Answer (score 0):

> In Vue 3 you can have multiple apps and you can no longer add to Vue prototype.

In order to write and use a plugin, follow the steps:

#### Step 1: Create the plugin

```js
export default {
  install: (app, options) => {
    class InitSocket {
      constructor(options) {
        this.options = options;
      }

      connect() {
        console.log(this.options);
      }
    }
    
    // inject a globally available $socket() method
    app.config.globalProperties.$socket = new InitSocket(options)
  }
}
```

#### Step 2: Import and install it in main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from "./App.vue";
import Sockets from './plugins/Socket'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(Sockets , "test");
app.mount("#app");
```

Read more on the Vue docs: [Plugins](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html#plugins)

Comment: Still says `Error: $socket is not defined`