# Using global properties outside vue components - Vue 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have custom service instances created in `main.ts`

```
app.config.globalProperties.$service1 = new Service1();
app.config.globalProperties.$service2 = new Service2();
```

I can use these instances inside vue components but I want to be able to use them in some utility files.

In vue 2 it was like:

```
import Vue from "vue";
Vue.prototype.$service1.someMethod("foo");
```

The only option that worked for me is to export the `app` instance in `main.ts` and importing it in my utility files but that did not look right.

What is the equivalent of `Vue.prototype` in Vue 3?

How to keep it singleton and still use the instances outside vue components?

Comment: perhaps you searched for the wrong thing ... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100658/add-global-variable-in-vue-js-3) question and answer came up when I searched using the title you used in your question

Comment: This is XY problem. You shouldn't do what you try to do. If you have a service, just import it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no good reasons for this code to be written in main.ts, then there won't be a necessity to get service instance frome a place it doesn't belong to.

With the benefits of modular JS, service instance can be defined in a module:

```
export default new Service1();
```

Then the service is imported in every module it's used:

```
import service1 from '.../service';
```

It's unnecessary to expose it to all component instances like it's done with `Vue.prototype`, the latter is the remnant of non-modular Vue that used `Vue` variable as global namespace. Currently the exposure of global dependencies through `app.config.globalProperties` is only needed for those that are supposed to be used in component templates, e.g. filters.