# import is undined until I add an extra console.log

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, hot-reload

I have a Vue3 project(setted up using vue-cli and run as `npm run serve`) which need a `const` to be defined so that all services can use it. so my `main.js` has this constant

```
// main.js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import "jquery"
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";

let x = 'google'
export {x};

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(store)
app.use(router)
app.mount("#app")
```

my `services/GetCategoriesService.js` is:

```
import { x } from "../main.js"

console.log(x)
```

and in my `components/footer.vue` `<script>` tag i execute the service script:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
import "../services/GetCategoriesService"
```

This will result in undefined but adding an extra console.log in my service will make hot reloading(I'm NOT refreshing the page)to run and now i can see two console.log with `google` then I refresh the page and again see two console.log but with `undefined` adding another console.log without refreshing result in three google prints, refresh Then I see three `undefined` which is really weird. I'm using Firefox `v 105.0`.

NOTE: Using named export of `x` and console.log `x` inside a function(which is called from `footer.vue`) result in same behavior.

Comment: I've never needed to `import` anything from `main.js` when using `vuejs` - so, not sure why you do - but then I've never used `jquery` with `vuejs`, so I wouldn't be surprised if jquery is messing up your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add global variable in Vue.js 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100658/add-global-variable-in-vue-js-3)

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm using jquery so that I can use it's ```post``` and ```get``` methods. anyway removing ```jquery``` and ```bootstrap``` imports doesnt affect this behavior

Comment: Fair enough - there's really no need to use jquery just for ajax, there are far better solutions for ajax - anyway, yoduh's link is all you need - I'd suggest the provide/inject methodology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a kind of circular import. To understand what is going on, first, we need to know how the `import` work.

The `import` process is divided into 3 steps:

1. **Construction:** find, download, and parse all of the files into
   module records.
2. **Instantiation:** find boxes in memory to place all of the exported
   values in (but don’t fill them in with values yet). Then make both
   exports and imports point to those boxes in memory. This is called
   linking.
3. **Evaluation:** run the code to fill in the boxes with the variables’
   actual values.

##### The normal case:

```js
// main.js
import { x } from './x'
console.log(x)

// x.js
let x = 1
export {x}
```

The `console.log(x)` above will print out `1` because the scenario will appear like below:

1. **Construction:** download and parse `main.js` -> download and parse `x.js`
2. **Instantiation:** find memory for `x` but don't fill in the value yet
3. **Evaluation:** run the code in `x.js` first (because it does not depend on any module) => set the value for `x` => run the code in `main.js` => show the expected value in the `console.log` because the value `x` has already been set

##### The circular import case:

```js
// main.js
import { x } from './x'
console.log(x)
let a = 2
export {a}

// x.js
import {a} from './main'
console.log(a)
let x = 1
export {x}
```

The `console.log(x)` in `main.js` will print out `1` but the `console.log(a)` in `x.js` will print out `undefined` because the `x.js` will still be run first. Because the JS engine will go down to the bottom of the dependencies graph and execute the module that is at the bottom (usually the module that does not depend on another)

##### Why does refreshing the page show `undefined` in the `console.log`?

Because it follows our scenario above

##### Why does hot-reload show the expected value in `console.log`?

Because the hot-reload process just replaces the module that changed. In your case, it is `GetCategoriesService.js`. So the `main.js` module is unchanged and its variable is already set the values

This answer is based on the knowledge in [this awesome article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/). Highly recommend reading it for the complete picture