# How to get $bvModal in setup?

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I upgrading my Vue 2 project to Vue 3 (BootstrapVue (2.23.1) with @vue/compat).  I facing serval problem.  The first problem is how to get $bvModal in setup?

Anybody known?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add global variable in Vue.js 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100658/add-global-variable-in-vue-js-3)

Comment: Thank you for reply, this link cannot help to me :(

Answer (score -1):

```
import {BootstrapVue, BModal } from 'bootstrap-vue'import { createApp } from '@vue/compat' //In setup> const { BModal } = inject('BModal') //use> const $bvModal = new BModal({ ref: 'modal'})
```

Comment: Actually, I need use $bvModal to use $bvModal.msgBoxConfirm but your answer cannot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).