# Global variables and functions with Quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I'm stucking in finding the right way to use some variables, utility functions and composables globally.
I want to avoid to import this in every component, page  etc.

Is there a technic like defining components globally? (e.g.  app.component("gCompShowError", gCompShowError);
It might be a silly question but I appreciate every hint.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since Vue 3 has introduced the composition API, there is no `this` keyword available in the `setup` function. So, there is no use in binding functions or variables into `Vue.prototype` or `app.config.globalProperties` to share common functionalities across the app globally. But, defining global components works properly.

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { App } from './App.vue'
import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue'

let app = createApp(App)

// Register global components
app.component('MyComponent', MyComponent);

app.mount('#app')
```

To define [global functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100658/add-global-variable-in-vue-js-3) (using mixins or plugins), you should use the `Options` interface instead. All Vue 2 exercises are available in the v3 Options interface, too.

```js
// Register global functions
app.config.globalProperties.$MyFunction = () => console.log('my custom fn');
```

Later you can use the `$MyFunction` in your Vue options API component:

```js
<template>
 <my-component/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$MyFunction();
  }
}
</script>
```

[It turned out](https://mokkapps.de/blog/why-i-love-vue-3-s-composition-api/), the composition API is more readable, maintainable, and scalable than the old Options API. All dependencies that a component or a composable function relies on, are obvious by looking at the imports.

In this case, if you want to reduce the import lines, you can re-export composition functions in `index.js` of the root directory.

```
src
-- composable
---- index.js
---- use-comp-1.js
---- use-comp-2.js
-- pages
---- HomePage.vue
```

```js
// src/composable/use-comp-1.js
export function useComp1() {
  return 1;
}

// src/composable/use-comp-2.js
export function useComp2() {
  return 2;
}

// src/composable/index.js
export { useComp1 } from 'src/composable/use-comp-1';
export { useComp2 } from 'src/composable/use-comp-2';


// HomePage.Vue
<script setup>
import { useComp1, useComp2 } from 'src/composable';

const a1 = useComp1();
const a2 = useComp2();
</script>
```

### Summary

In absence of the `this` keyword in the setup function, using global functions is not possible. On the other hand, composition API provides a better way of writing maintainable codes.