Running app.config inside Vue component returns undefined
My app's main.js looks like this:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)
const globalProps = app.config.globalProperties

app.use(router).mount('#app')


globalProps.msg = 'one, two, three'

And I've got a component App.vue which looks like this:
<template>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<script setup>
  console.log(app.config)
</script>

<style>
  @import 'assets/style.css';
</style>

When I run app.config so I can access the globalProperties from within my component, it returns undefined. What am I doing wrong?

it's strange it even works, app isn't even defined in the component, there should be an error

@AlexanderNenashev this is the app structure generated by Vue CLI

I don't think you can access global properties using the script setup in VueJS. Consider using the provide/inject method. Look at the accepted answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100658/add-global-variable-in-vue-js-3

This can be done as shown in the answer, but as said, the proper way is inject() or a composable that wraps it.

@EstusFlask So, I should 'provide' from App.vue and 'inject' in any component I need these properties available on? instead of using built in globalProperties?

@gespinha Yes, like shows the question linked above. With composition api globalProperties is used for rare things that need to be always available in a template, like i18n's t().

Use getCurrentInstance() to get the current component's reference and its app:
import {getCurrentInstance} from 'vue'
const self = getCurrentInstance();
const config = self.appContext.app.config;

