# highjack minified builded dist folder to change a api backend target

Tags: vue.js, axios, environment-variables, production-environment, vue-cli

### Explanation

i have a dist build of my Vue-CLI App. inside i am using .env vars to handle my Axios.baseURL for my entire APP.
ofc in **dev** mode i am using a dev Backend and DB, in **stage**, using a mirror of master Backend and DB, and on **master** the correct Backend and DB for production.

what i want is to build with `npm run build` to create a stage (testable product) and then if the tests results positiv, move the whole dist folder to my production without changing anything of the dist folder, because i know the compiled stuff inside this very dist folder is ready for production.

then i need a config.js that changes the Axios.baseURL for this dist compiled folder afterwards to target the API Requests to another, my production Backend and DB

any ideas how to accomplish this? like a .env file but no .env file.
i know it sounds confusing but this is what i need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing to do is to use some shell utility (like [sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159367/using-sed-to-find-and-replace)) to simply "search and replace" the URL in the compiled js bundle...

If you really want do that *without changing anything*, only option is to remove the URL (or other config) from your app and make it *external* global variable declared by some other js file, which then needs to be included in the page before your app bundle. [step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59576534/381282)

Search and replace seems much more straightforward tho....